# Adding new row to table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have searched and found similar answers to this but not exactly and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong... Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
<html><head>
<script>
function doTheInsert() {
  var newRow=document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow();
  newRow="<td>New row text</td><td>New row 2nd cell</td>";
}
</script></head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>First row</td>
    <td>First row 2nd cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second row</td>
    <td>more stuff</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="doTheInsert()" value="Insert new row"> 
</body></html>
```

Comment: `createElement`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose it would be more formally correct to use `insertCell` for each added cell, but just dropping in the whole string will work if you set newRow's innerHTML:

```
function doTheInsert() {
  var newRow=document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow();
  // newRow = "<td>New row text</td><td>New row 2nd cell</td>"; <-- won't work
  newRow.innerHTML = "<td>New row text</td><td>New row 2nd cell</td>";
}
```

```js
function doTheInsert() {
  var newRow=document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow();
  newRow.innerHTML="<td>New row text</td><td>New row 2nd cell</td>";
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>First row</td>
    <td>First row 2nd cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second row</td>
    <td>more stuff</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="doTheInsert()" value="Insert new row">
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell), you need to add cells to the row after creating it.

```js
function doTheInsert() {
  var newRow=document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow();
    // Insert a cell in the row at cell index 0
  var cell1   = newRow.insertCell(0);

  // Append a text node to the cell
  var cell1Text  = document.createTextNode('New row text')
  cell1.appendChild(cell1Text);

  // Insert a cell in the row at cell index 1
  var cell2   = newRow.insertCell(1);

  // Append a text node to the cell
  var cell2Text  = document.createTextNode('New row 2nd cell')
  cell2.appendChild(cell2Text);
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>First row</td>
    <td>First row 2nd cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second row</td>
    <td>more stuff</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="doTheInsert()" value="Insert new row">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function doTheInsert() {
  newRow="<td>New row text</td><td>New row 2nd cell</td>";
  document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML += newRow;
}
```

Been a while since i did normal javascript. But this should work. Probably not the nicest way to do it.

Comment: This does appear to work, with the one caveat that it generates an extra `<tbody>` along with each added row...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using this instead:

```
<html><head>
    <script>
        function doTheInsert() {
            var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
            var newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
            var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
            var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);

            newCell1.innerHTML = "New row text";
            newCell2.innerHTML = "New row 2nd Cell";
            //newRow="<td>New row text</td><td>New row 2nd cell</td>";
        }
</script></head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>First row</td>
            <td>First row 2nd cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Second row</td>
            <td>more stuff</td>
       </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="doTheInsert()" value="Insert new row"> 
</body></html>
```

The `.insertRow(-1)` will append the new row to the end of the table, or use `.insertRow(0)` to prepend the new row to the table.